Deployment fail issue in AWS elastic beanstalk
I have developed an end to end Machine learning application. I want to deploy it on aws elastic beanstalk, I am new to aws and I am a complete beginner. I have tried to create a elastic beanstalk application and then create a code pipeline. Everything is working fine and even the codepipeline is working fine, when I try to open the deployed link of nginx I am getting error 502 from nginx.
[![](https://i.sstatic.net/M6g4Husp.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/M6g4Husp.png)
